# Suggestions to debug Google Play Integrity DecodeIntegrityToken API

Tags: python-2.7, google-api, google-play-developer-api, google-cloud-console, google-play-integrity-api

Trying to figure out how to use Google's play-integrity api to verify nonces.
I've hit this roadblock and am unsure what other things I could try to debug and get more information out of this API. Below is a series of steps I've taken to get to the point I'm currently at.

**What I've done:**

Created a service account within the Google Cloud project with the grants:

- Service Account User and Service Usage Consumer
- Setup Google Auth Default Credentials
- Set [environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials#personal):GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS by pulling down imported json from service account.

**Where I'm at now:**

- Used google-api-client to build and call playintegrity, resulting in the response:

Code snippet:

```
response = service.v1().decodeIntegrityToken(
  packageName='com.myapp.package',
  body={
    'integrityToken':'superLongString'
    }
).execute()

raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting
https://playintegrity.googleapis.com/v1/com.myapp.package:decodeIntegrityToken?alt=json
returned "Integrity token cannot be decoded due to invalid arguments.". 
Details: "Integrity token cannot be decoded due to invalid arguments.">
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to better understand how to call decodeIntegrityToken with the right parameters or configurations to retrieve a 200. It is not immediately clear to me which of it is is and what the next steps to debug are.

Resources used:

- https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#returned-payload-format
- [Decode integrity token using Google PlayIntegrity API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71526352/decode-integrity-token-using-google-playintegrity-api/72566344#72566344)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are receiving an `INTEGRITY_INVALID_ARGUMENT` check one of the following:

- arguments in body_request are incorrect.
- `integrity_token`, which is retrieved by google upon sending over a nonce. Note that this `integrity_token` needs to be correct or else it will still send the same error message above.